# Need subtract values from one table to another VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have two tables, one is the inventory table and the other is the sales table.
I need to subtract articles from the inventory table using data from the sales table.

The common fields are 'id' in table 1 (inventory) and 'id_reg' in table 2 (sales).

Is it possible to update values if the field names are not the same, or do I need to change the field name of 'id_reg' to 'id'?

I've attempted to use a 'Do … While' loop, but I got confused.

Comment: I think you might need to tell more details about what you tried and how it failed exactly, preferably additionally posting some code, so that readers can understand better what your problem is. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, no, you don't need the fields you want to match in different tables to have the same name. Just specify the right field from each table in whatever code you write.

Comment: Please give sample data from both tables (so we can see the structures) and the desired output. What you ask is possible (without seeing details) and not complex, doesn't need fields renaming but we need to see some sample data.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding your question about the field names, no need to change the “id_reg” field name (the foreign key field name) to be “id” (the primary key field name).

To accomplish that we'll proceed with the following assumptions:

- The “inventory” table contains the inventory of the articles in one store.
- The “inventory” table contains the following fields: “id” (for item code), “invquant” (for inventory quantity of the item)
- The “sales” table contains the following fields: “id_reg” (for item code), “quantity” (for sales quantity)
- Our goal is to subtract the sum of the values in the "quantity" field of the "sales" table from the corresponding "invquant" field in the "inventory" table for each item.
- We need to perform this deduction operation for all items in the "sales" table, and this operation should occur only once (though it's worth noting that in practice, you should deduct the sales quantity from the inventory when saving each sales record).

To achieve such task we have two primary approaches:

**Approach 1: Using SQL Command (Recommended)**

You can use a SQL command to deduct all the quantities in the "sales" table from their corresponding quantities in the "inventory" table.

Here's the recommended SQL command:

```
UPDATE inventory FROM (SELECT id_reg, SUM(quantity) AS totquant FROM sales GROUP BY id_reg) AS salesquant WHERE inventory.id = salesquant.id_reg SET inventory.invquant = inventory.invquant - salesquant.totquant
```

**Approach 2: Looping through Records (Not Recommended)**

Alternatively, you can loop through the records in the "sales" table one by one and deduct the quantity from the "inventory" table.

However, this approach is not recommended for efficiency reasons.

```
  USE inventory IN 0
  USE Sales IN 0
  SELECT sales
  SCAN 
    SELECT inventory
    LOCATE FOR id = Sales.id_reg 
    REPLACE invquant WITH invquant - Sales.quantity 
  ENDSCAN
```

Note that if the "inventory" table has an index on the "id" field, you can optimize the code as follows:

```
  USE inventory IN 0 ORDER TAG id
  USE Sales IN 0
  SELECT sales
  SCAN 
    SELECT inventory
    SEEK Sales.id_reg 
    REPLACE invquant WITH invquant - Sales.quantity 
  ENDSCAN
```

Alternatively, you can establish a relation between the "sales" table and the "inventory" table:

```
 USE inventory IN 0 ORDER TAG id
  USE Sales IN 0
  SELECT sales
  SET RELATION TO id_reg INTO inventory
  SCAN 
    SELECT inventory
    REPLACE invquant WITH invquant - Sales.quantity 
  ENDSCAN
```

Please choose the approach that best suits your requirements, keeping in mind that the SQL command is the recommended and more efficient method.